# MySQL/MariaDB connection in asp code encodes wrongly charset utf8 at insert or update in data base

Tags: mysql, utf-8, vba, mariadb-10.1

I can't get a simple update or insert to save special äöü characters. Instead they are being stored as Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼.

The website displays äöü characters correctly if they are already stored as äöü in the database using phpMyAdmin (or some other tool like HeidiSQL), but for some reason I can't use my code/connection to the database to store them properly. This is where I stand:

I added `charset=utf8` to my connection string:

```
MM_Connection_STRING = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};port=3306;SERVER=localhost;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;database=xxx;Option=3;charset=utf8"
```

I added `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to all my forms.

I am running MariaDB and IIS 10.

```
Server version:         10.1.13-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:       10
```

The page gets proxied using Apache 2.4. I am running asp (classic) code.

Calling the MySQL server for character and collation, I get this:

```
MariaDB> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR
  Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

The code worked when I was using iso-8859-1 as charset.

Any help will be very much appropriated. Thank you.

Comment: Update: I just discovered that doing a `response.write(request.querystring("val")` from a URL containing the values `&val=äöü` that the äöü characters are being transcoded to Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼. It's no wonder that things are not lining up. IIS 10 should have a setting for that, or I may have to code something to fix it.

Comment: Use the `SELECT..HEX..` suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 to see whether it was stored correctly or not.  For correctly stored utf8, expect hex `C3A4 C3B6 C3BC` for `äöü`.

Comment: Thank you [Rick James](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) for the link. Yes, the `SELECT g, HEX(g) FROM table` test turned out positive. The `CODEPAGE="65001"` declaration change did the trick for asp classic to encode in utf8. (No need to declare charset in connection string.)

Comment: Have you tested the `HEX` after dropping the `charset` from the connection string?  I think they are both important, and handle radically different things.

Answer (score 0):

I had `<%@language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252" LCID=1033%>` and needed `<%@language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" LCID=1033%>` for it to work. Also, after doing this I needed to drop `charset=utf8` from the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for that; I added it to my [long list](http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages).